# Is there a way to hide aria and events in devtools element properties

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Devtools under elements > properties:

There are a large number of properties for a tag that I rarely need, mostly the aria and events.

I am always having to scroll through these to find the properties I want to view.
Is there a way to filter them out?

Comment: They removed this panel in the future Chrome completely. Maybe they'll introduce an alternative way to invoke it. Either way it wouldn't be customizable. You can write a [devtools snippet](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets) that uses console.log on `$0` and shows only the properties you want, and invoke it via `Ctrl-P`, `!`

Comment: That looks to be the best option. But I cannot seem to find a way to list the property names. Object.keys($0) only returns 1 key: "d" regardless of which element. Any Idea why?

Comment: They're in the prototype chain so use a for-in loop e.g. (() => { let props = {}; for (const k in $0) props[k] = $0[k]; return props; })()